# How to left-align some (not all) single-line, labeled equations in beamer? I tried ```fleqn``` but it gives problems

Tags: beamer, equations, horizontal-alignment, cross-referencing, equation-number

I'm working on a presentation with beamer, and I use the `equation` environment in two cases:

1. a line with only mathematical expressions, between two lines of text, and centered horizontally (pretty much the standard case, see the first equation in the MWE below)
2. some text paragraph (outside math environment) juxtaposed to an equation (like the second and third equations in the MWE below)

To attain the latter, I use the `minipage` environment. I used to use the `columns` environment, but it is much more difficult to tune into the right kind of visual alignment.

The motivation for doing so is that the text paragraph gives a description or definition of the formula appearing on its side. However, simply putting the text and the `\begin{equation}`[...]`\end{equation}` in adjacent `minipage`s results in a gap in between that I find ugly and I'd like to fill - more precisely, I'd like the text and formula to be closer to each other near the center of the slide (see the difference between the second and third equations in the MWE below).

I found that this can be achieved by putting the text in a `flushright` environment and by enclosing the `equation` environment into an `fleqn` enviroment (loading the `nccmath` package). Note that I do not want *all* the equations to be aligned on the left, so I'm not using `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` in the preamble <s>(which, anyway, simply does not work in beamer as it raises an option clash error)</s>.

I'm not using `flalign` or similar as they appear not to achieve the desired result for single-line equations, but only to work when equations on two or more rows need to be left-aligned.

**The problem:** Everything works fine until I try to cross-reference equations. Indeed, if I give a `\label` to an equation inside the `fleqn` environment and try to reference it somewhere else with `\ref{}`, the latter results in a number that is not the same displayed near the equation itself.

I've seen several answers around on similar questions but very few concern beamer (hence the issue with `fleqn`) and none solved my issue.

Any help is very welcome!

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    An equation outside of the \verb|fleqn| environment. I give it the label: \verb|\label{eq1}|.
    \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
        F = ma
    \end{equation}

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            Text on the side equation in \verb|fleqn| \\
            (the equation has label: \verb|\label{eq2}|)
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.5em}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
        \begin{fleqn}
            \begin{equation}\label{eq2}
                \delta q = {\rm d}u + P\,{\rm d}v
            \end{equation}
        \end{fleqn}
    \end{minipage}\\
    \vspace{1.5em}

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            Text on the side equation without \verb|fleqn| \\
            (the equation has label: \verb|\label{eq3}|)
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{1em}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}\label{eq3}
            \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \nabla\cdot\left(\rho\vec{v}\right) = 0
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}\\
    \vspace{1em}
    
    Note, in the latter case, the space between text and equation, that I'd like to fill.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item   Here I reference the first equation, using \verb|\ref{eq1}|: Eq.~\ref{eq1}.
        \item   Here I reference the second equation, using \verb|\ref{eq2}|: Eq.~\ref{eq2}.
        \item   Here I reference the third equation, using \verb|\ref{eq3}|: Eq.~\ref{eq3}.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image: Slide obtained from the MWE above]

Comment: "which, anyway, simply does not work in beamer as it raises an option clash error" That's what the `\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}` option is for.

Comment: I was not aware of this (I should have guessed, tho). Thanks for pointing it out, I have edited my question accordingly. Still, toggling the ```fleqn``` option is not helping, as already pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach using the `varwidth` package (this will centre the complete block of text+equation):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    An equation outside of the \verb|fleqn| environment. I give it the label: \verb|\label{eq1}|.
    \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
        F = ma
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
      \text{\begin{varwidth}{.4\textwidth}
          \raggedleft
          Text on the side equation in \\
          (the equation has label: )
      \end{varwidth}\quad
      }
        \delta q = {\rm d}u + P\,{\rm d}v
        \label{eq2}
    \end{equation}
    
    Note, in the latter case, the space between text and equation, that I'd like to fill.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item   Here I reference the first equation, using \verb|\ref{eq1}|: Eq.~\ref{eq1}.
        \item   Here I reference the second equation, using \verb|\ref{eq2}|: Eq.~\ref{eq2}.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you prefer a minipage of fixed width (this will centre the left edge of the equation):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    An equation outside of the \verb|fleqn| environment. I give it the label: \verb|\label{eq1}|.
    \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
        F = ma
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
      \text{\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
          \raggedleft
          Text on the side equation in \\
          (the equation has label: )
      \end{minipage}\quad
      }
        \delta q = {\rm d}u + P\,{\rm d}v
        \hskip \textwidth minus \textwidth
        \label{eq2}
    \end{equation}
    
    Note, in the latter case, the space between text and equation, that I'd like to fill.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item   Here I reference the first equation, using \verb|\ref{eq1}|: Eq.~\ref{eq1}.
        \item   Here I reference the second equation, using \verb|\ref{eq2}|: Eq.~\ref{eq2}.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, both your suggestions are good. Basically your solution is to just put the text inside the ```equation``` environment, which seems way better than my approach. Could you explain what's the meaning of the ```\hskip \textwidth minus \textwidth``` part?

Comment: @AmenoParallasse The `\hskip \textwidth minus \textwidth` will occupy all the available space on the right hand side of the equation and thus will make the centred equation look left aligned.

Comment: I see, clever. Accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: @AmenoParallasse You're welcome!